# Converting MySql table to BerkelyDB

Tags: mysql, berkeley-db

Is it possible to convert mySQL tables to the BerkelyDB(Sleepycat) format, is there any utility available.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? I believe prior to 5.1, MySQL included BDB engine.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but since MySQL 5.0 supports BDB, you should be able to do:

`ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = DBD;`

Make sure to backup your data before attempting this.

Also, I do not believe mysqld by default starts with BDB enabled, to enable it, you have to start mysqld with `mysqld-max`